# Inline SVG does not scale to height

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm embedding an SVG inline with this code:

```
<div id="svgInlineDiv" style='background-color:white'></div>

<script>
    document.addEventListener("onload",inlineSVG(),false);
    function inlineSVG()
    {
        var SVGFile="img/office_lights.svg";
        var loadXML = new XMLHttpRequest;
        function handler(){
            if(loadXML.readyState == 4 && loadXML.status == 200)
                svgInlineDiv.innerHTML=loadXML.responseText
        }
        if (loadXML != null){
            loadXML.open("GET", SVGFile, true);
            loadXML.onreadystatechange = handler;
            loadXML.send();
        }
    }
</script>
```

The SVG header looks like this:

```
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   id="svg9948"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.48.5 r10040"
   sodipodi:docname="office_lights_source.svg"
   viewBox="0 0 1229.4684 1144.845"
   width="100%"
   height="100%">
```

This image scales only to the width of the browser windows, but not its height.

The picture is roughly square. When I resize the browser window to be higher than it is wide, it is displayed nicely at full width. But when I resize the browser window to be wider than it is high (as one usually does on a widescreen monitor), the picture still shows at full width, forcing me to scroll down to see the lower part.

I've tried playing around with `width` and `height` in the CSS as well as the SVG, but to no avail.

**EDIT:**

Solved by adding `height: 100vh` to the `div`s style.
Thanks, Paul LeBeau.

Comment: In your example the `div` has no dimensions, so what should `100%` mean there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your `<div>` have any styling?  If not, it will have a width of 100% and a height that matches the height of it's children.  In this case that will be the height of the SVG.

The SVG width is being scaled to 100% of the `<div>` width, which is 100% of the page width.

The height of the SVG is being calculated so that the SVG's aspect ratio (as described by the `viewBox`) is maintained.  So, for example, if your page width is 1024px, the height of the SVG, *and hence the `<div>`*, will be:

```
1024 * (1144.845 / 1229.4684) = 953.53
```

If you want to restrict the SVG and div to the height of the screen/page, then you will need to use one of the various methods for doing that.  For example

[Make div 100% height of browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window)

Then the SVG will scale to the height of the div.  How exactly it gets scaled within the div will depend on the value of the SVG's `preserveAspectRatio` attribute.  You can read about how this attribute works here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute